# Multi series export is misaligned in highcharts

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I have a highcharts with two yAxis. The second yAxis have a '300px' top value. When I click on 'Download as PNG', a PNG file downloads and the downloaded image is misaligned.

This is my javascript

```
  Highcharts.chart('container', {

    title: {
        text: ''
    },

    subtitle: {
        text: ''
    },

    chart: {
        type: 'line'
    },

    yAxis: [{
    height: 200,
    },
    {
    height: 200,
    top: 200,
    }],

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
            'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 126.0, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
        yAxis : 0,
    },
    {
        data: [54.9, 95.5, 194.4, 216.2, 148.0, 126.0, 135.6, 176.0, 144.5, 129.4, 106.1, 71.6, 29.4],
        yAxis: 1,
    }]
});
```

[This is my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hakkim/o8s5wz3x/24/)

Can anyone help me to sort this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That issue is a Highcharts bug and it is reported here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/11509

As a workaround, you can set:

- `height` as a chart property:

```
    chart: {
        ...,
        height: 600
    },
```

or:

- `height` style directly on the container:

```
    document.getElementById('container').style.height = '600px';
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ot2fa94v/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.height